# Add friend button PHP/SQL

Tags: php

I'm creating an add user button, but, when there are multiple users on the same page, they all get added on click.

Here is the code:

$data_emails is an array containing users emails.

```
    <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data_emails); $i ++) {
         echo $data_emails[$i] . ' ' . $data_usernames[$i] . '<br />';
         $email2 = $data_emails[$i];
         $contact = $data_usernames[$i];
         if (relationship_exists($email, $email2) === false) {
    ?>              
    <form action="" name="add_user" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="add_user" value="Add user" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
          }
          if (isset($_POST['add_user']))
             create_relationship($email, $email2, $contact);                                                   
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as Javascript ?

Comment: you at least need to show us your `insertUser` function

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you have everything in a loop. So it is functioning like this. Try out following code.

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data_emails); $i ++) 
    {
        echo $data_emails[$i] . ' ' . $data_usernames[$i] . '<br />';
        $email2 = $data_emails[$i];
        $contact = $data_usernames[$i];
        if (relationship_exists($email, $email2) === false) 
        {
            ?>              
            <form action="" name="add_user" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="email2" value="<?php echo $email2?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="contact" value="<?php echo $contact?>">
                <input type="submit" name="add_user" value="Add user" />
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['add_user']))
    {
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['add_user']);
        $email2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email2']);
        $contact = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['contact']);

        create_relationship($email, $email2, $contact);
    }        
?>
```